# Php replace * with <b> tags

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-replace-callback

I want to replace `*asd*` with `<b>asd</b>` in my string.

```
*Abdāl* (*lit*: substitutes, but which can also mean generous [*karīm*]
```

In the above string, I want to replace `*abdal*` with `<b>abdal</b>` and also the other words that are enclosed with *.

How can I do this?

Mycode:

`$s="*Abdāl* (*lit*: substitutes, but which can also mean generous [*karīm*]";

preg_replace_callback("#\*[^\*]*\*#",function ($string) {
 $string = preg_replace("/<a\s(.+?)>(.+?)<\/a>/is", "<b>$2</b>", $string);
                    }, $s);`

I am able to get the `*abdal*` string as matches inside the preg_replace_callback but now am trying to replace `*abdal*` to `<b>abdal</b>`.

Comment: show what you've tried...

Comment: A naive solution would be to start with the regex `\*([^*]+)\*`, try something yourself with that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use a simple call to `preg_replace` and use a regex with a capturing group over the value inside asterisks and a string replacement pattern with a placeholder to group 1:

```
$s = "*Abdāl* (*lit*: substitutes, but which can also mean generous [*karīm*]";
$s = preg_replace("#\*([^*]+)\*#", "<b>$1</b>", $s);
echo $s; // => <b>Abdāl</b> (<b>lit</b>: substitutes, but which can also mean generous [<b>karīm</b>]
```

See the [PHP demo](http://rextester.com/CPI50195).

The regex is `\*([^*]+)\*` and it matches `*`, then matches *and captures into Group 1* any one or more chars other than `*` (with `[^*]+` - note the `*` does not have to be escaped inside the character class, and if you need to also process empty `**` pairs, replace `+` with your `*` quantifier), and then matches a trailing `*`. The replacement pattern contains `$1` that references the text stored in Group 1.

See the [**regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/8Y8846/1).

Answer (score 1):

```
$s="*Abdāl* (*lit*: substitutes, but which can also mean generous [*karīm*]";                                       
$s = preg_replace_callback("#\*[^\*]*\*#", function ($string) {
        $string = preg_replace("/\*([^*]+)\*/", "<b>$1</b>", $string);
        return $string[0];
       }, $s);
```

This worked for me.